# Kotlin single equal sign "=" object assignment time complexity

Tags: java, kotlin, big-o

What is the time complexity of object assignment using the equals sign in Kotlin (or Java)?

```
fun moveZeroes(nums: IntArray): Unit {
    var numsCopy = nums
}
```

More specifically if I have my own object ListNode

```
 * Example:
 * var li = ListNode(5)
 * var v = li.`val`
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * class ListNode(var `val`: Int) {
 *     var next: ListNode? = null
 * }
 */
```

What would be the copy time below?

```
fun mergeTwoLists(l1: ListNode?, l2: ListNode?): ListNode? {
    var l1Copy = l1
}
```

I find myself often doing this assignment since ListNode passes as val, and I can't do

```
l1 = l1?.next
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment

```
var l1Copy = l1
```

does not make a new `ListNode` object that contains the same properties as `l1`. It just creates a new variable called `l1Copy` and points it to the same memory location as `l1`, so it's an *O(1)* operation.

In the following code

```
fun f(n: ListNode) {
    var n1 = n
}

val node = ListNode(1)
val var1 = node
f(node)
```

there's only one object, `ListNode(1)`, and three variables pointing to it: `node` and `var1` in the global scope, and `n` and `n1` in `f`'s scope.

Comment: This answer is correct. A list is an object, and objects are always passed by reference, even for assignments. To copy, OP must use a respective `copy()` function. This should be added to the answer.

Comment: Great answer thanks. So in my first example I was passing list node in to the function as a parameter. All parameters are passed as val in kotlin. If I do the `var l1Copy = l1` how does l1Copy become mutable if `l1` was immutable and `l1Copy` is just a pointer to the same memory location? Changing `l1Copy` doesn't seem to change `l1`

Answer (score 0):

If method contains only assignment statements that are constant time, if-statements, conditional expressions, and
the like, chances are that it is a constant-time operation or method. If it contains a loop, chances are that it is not
constant-time.

But you have to be careful, as the following example shows.
Consider an array b and the following statements:

```java
int sum= 0;
for (int k= 0; k < Math.min(50, b.length); k= k+1)
    sum= sum + b[k];
```

Since the loop iterates at most 50 times, and since each expression or assignment in it is a constant-time operation,
the code itself is constant time. It has a maximum of 50 array-element additions, for example, no matter how big the
array is. But the following loop with initialization is not constant time but takes time proportional to the size of b.

```java
int sum= 0;
for (int k= 0; k < b.length; k= k+1)
   sum= sum + b[k];
```